# Fragment doesn't show second time it's used

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-appcompat, preferencefragment

I have a single `Activity` architecture where I'm loading a `PreferenceFragmentCompat` inside another `ViewGroup` in the `MainActivity`. Custom navigation exists within the `MainActivity` so that you can load the `ViewGroup` with the fragment and navigate away from it all within the same `MainActivity`.

The first time I navigate to the `ViewGroup`, the `PreferenceFragmentCompat` loads perfectly fine. However, when I navigate away from the `ViewGroup` containing the `PreferenceFragmentCompat` and then back again, the `PreferenceFragmentCompat` does not show up subsequent times. The `ViewGroup` does, but it's empty where the fragment should be. I can see through breakpoints/logging that the fragment is going through its lifecycle--it just isn't visible.

A new containing `ViewGroup` and a new `PreferenceFragmentCompat` object pair is created every time I navigate back to the `ViewGroup`, so it shouldn't be getting attached to an old `ViewGroup`. The navigation architecture is too complicated to post here, but here's how I'm adding the fragment in the containing `ViewGroup` class each time:

```
CustomPreferenceFragment fragment = new CustomPreferenceFragment();
FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.fragment_frame_container, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

Does anyone have any idea why the fragment might not be showing up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. It was a lot simpler than I expected. Because a new `ViewGroup` was being created every time, the fragment was being added to the old `ViewGroup` before it could be replaced by the new one, since they both contain the `R.id.fragment_frame_container` view. The solution was to just not create a new `ViewGroup` each time if it already existed.